# Visual Studio 2013 (WPF) не отображаются элементы на странице

Tags: visual-studio, wpf

Знатоки Visual Studio/WPF подскажите пожалуйста, почему у меня на странице не отображаются элементы? При наведении курсором появляются очертания элементов и при запуске всё отображается. Спасибо!

**Скрин из Visual Studio:** http://s020.radikal.ru/i716/1505/d5/3c15a50ca00e.png

**Код XAML:**

```
<Page
x:Name="pageRoot"
x:Class="Save_The_Humans.MainPage"
DataContext="{Binding DefaultViewModel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Save_The_Humans"
xmlns:common="using:Save_The_Humans.Common"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Page.Resources>
    <!-- TODO: Delete this line if the key AppName is declared in App.xaml -->
    <x:String x:Key="AppName">Save the Humans</x:String>
</Page.Resources>
<Page.Background>
    <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill"/>
</Page.Background>

<!--
    This grid acts as a root panel for the page that defines two rows:
    * Row 0 contains the back button and page title
    * Row 1 contains the rest of the page layout
-->
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="160"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="160"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
        <TransitionCollection>
            <EntranceThemeTransition/>
        </TransitionCollection>
    </Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="140"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="160"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!-- Back button and page title -->
    <Grid Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button x:Name="backButton" Margin="39,59,39,0" Command="{Binding NavigationHelper.GoBackCommand, ElementName=pageRoot}"
                    Style="{StaticResource NavigationBackButtonNormalStyle}"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    AutomationProperties.Name="Back"
                    AutomationProperties.AutomationId="BackButton"
                    AutomationProperties.ItemType="Navigation Button"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="pageTitle" Text="{StaticResource AppName}" Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}" Grid.Column="1" 
                    IsHitTestVisible="false" TextWrapping="NoWrap" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,30,40"/>
    </Grid>
    <Button x:Name="startButton" Content="Start!" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="36,40,0,0" Grid.Row="2" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="32" Width="89" RenderTransformOrigin="0.384,-0.758"/>
    <ProgressBar Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="10" Margin="631,103,0,0" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
    <ContentControl Content="ContentControl" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="36,103,0,0" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Canvas Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="434,202,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: А вы не пробовали удалить все внутренние элементы из XAML, кроме одного? Не думаю, что все они важны для данного примера.

Comment: И [`EntranceThemeTransition`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.entrancethemetransition.Aspx) выглядит как что-то из репертуара Windows 8 RT, а не классического WPF.